# How to fade a message when HTML page loads + Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want when the index page load in my browser the current div will be fade out after 3 seconds. When that `div` hide the main content of the page (menu,images,etc) show. I also use bootstrap css in my page

I get stack in the following  problem. 
The problem is that my JS function isn't working.

Here is the body of my html page so far:

```
<body> <div id="fade">
        <div id="box">
          <blockquote class="blockquote-reverse">
                <p>Blah Blah</p>
                <footer>Project Manager of <cite title="Source Title">Some project</cite></footer>
        </blockquote>
       </div>
     </div>

<!-- blah blah here comes the rest of the site --> </body>
```

Here is my css file:

```
#box {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

#fade {
    height:100vh;
    background-color: black;
}
```

and here is the JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#box').delay(300).fadeOut(300);
});
```

Note that I use BootStrap (as i said earlier).

Comment: If you could create a fiddle reproducing the problem, that would be helpful. Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: try use  $(window).load(function(){ ..fadeOut here ...});

Comment: delay('milliseconds') - meaning you have 300 milliseconds wait time, you'll want 3000 in there for 3 seconds

Comment: no sir. I re write the problem as I fix my CSS issue. I don't know how to hide the div now and show the other elements (which are under the div)

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef no nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.load()` instead of `.ready()`, because `load` wait until your page is loaded all its content,  but `ready`, when the script is ready.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // your code
});
```

And you don't need `delay`.

Here's a living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sox59a1a/

Comment: Did you check the demo?

Comment: yes. And that's not my problem. I want the `fade` div to hide all the other containts of the page not to shown under it. And then when it fade out to revelie them

Comment: anyway I fix the second problem but the fadeout not.

Comment: You meant, hide all `div`?

Comment: `$('#fade').fadeOut(300);`

Comment: ok made it! Thank you. I just had problems with my computer. -.- Sorry for that!

Answer (score 0):

If I have not misunderstood, what you can do to do what you say is:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#fade").fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $("#restOfPage").fadeIn(1000); 
    });
});
```

It's a really basic example, but you can start to do what you want with this..

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/sox59a1a/3/

Comment: thank you for your try. The rest of the page fade in actions isn't required anymore. I edited the css and now I only need just the fade out actions which again isn't working.

Comment: I know that it can sound rude, but, did you import the jquery library ?

Comment: yes I checked it now. I added it correctly with Bootstrap and everything is working. But not my fade out function : `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Ok! Can you try to do a fiddle so we can see what specifically is making your headaches ? d:  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: `<script type="main.js"></script>` . I coded so many lines that that mistake was made me see red! Insteed of `type` of course we need `src`. God help the programmers! O>o